# Access and manage Azure resources from C#

Tags: .net, azure, powershell-cmdlet

I am writing a binary cmdlet to add records to a CosmosDb collection. I need the user to login to Azure (user credentials) and I can use PS commands to get the rest of the info.
I can do this in Powershell by using the [Get-AzCosmosDbAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.cosmosdb/get-azcosmosdbaccount?view=azps-4.8.0) given that the person has permissions in Azure to view the resource.

What I can't find is a way to do this in C# code. I have found several examples that come very close but fail to actually work. For example, I found [this example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/doc/mgmt_preview_quickstart.md) in the Azure SDK for .NET but I can't find a reference to the `Azure.ResourceManager.Resources` library.

I found [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/storage-dotnet-resource-provider-getting-started/storage-dotnet-resource-provider-getting-started/) but it uses app registration credentials to authenticate not user credentials. I need to use user credentials.

I want to do this PS Script, in C#:

```
Login-AzAccount
Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-cxxxxxxxxxxx | Select-AzSubscription
$cosmosKey = Get-AzCosmosDBAccountKey -ResourceGroupName 'rg-temp' -Name 'doctemp'
$cosmosKey.PrimaryMasterKey
```

Sadly, it's the `Login-AzAccount` that I can't understand.

Comment: why do you want to convert it to C#? how do you expect to provision your database and from where? Are you building an Azure DevOps pipeline? Is this to provision master records or use from inside a web/api application to add new data into your cosmosDB?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure all those questions are germaine to the answer I was asking for. Thank you for the interest and you can look to Alex AIT's answer below if you'd like to try this.

Comment: cause this question has no sense. If you are writing a cmdlet why do you want to convert it to C#? :-)

Comment: Why it's in C# has no bearing on the answer to the question. If you'd like to try Alex's answer it is below. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to use `new DefaultAzureCredential(true)` - the `true` will also enable interactive authentication for user credentials. You can also look at [this document](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity/README.md) for general information about authentication.

The following example uses nuget packages [Azure.Identity](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Identity) and
[Azure.ResourceManager.CosmosDB](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.ResourceManager.CosmosDB).
The latter is currently only available as a prerelease version. You could also try [Microsoft.Azure.Management.CosmosDB](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.CosmosDB/) instead.

```cs
var subscriptionId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID");
var client = new Azure.ResourceManager.CosmosDB.CosmosDBManagementClient(
       subscriptionId, new DefaultAzureCredential(true));
var keys = client.DatabaseAccounts.ListKeys("resourcegroupName", "accountname");
```

If you need to switch to a different tenant, you can set the `AZURE_TENANT_ID` environment variable.

Comment: You did it! I had three version specific references that had to be resolved but that works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos` package. With it you can connect to Cosmos DB using `CosmosClient` class:

```
this.cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(EndpointUri, PrimaryKey);
```

You can see more detailed tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-get-started).

Comment: That's not what I asked. I don't have the Primary Key, so I can't use that yet. I need to Get-AzCosmosDbAccount to get the keys for the account. Then I can use the keys to access the Collection.